# JAX WS Unknown Source Error while invoking service operation in a stand alone application

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am trying to invoke a jax ws operation like this :

```
MyService myProxy = getProxy();
boolean gmFlagUpdated = false; 
GmFlagUpdate gmFlagUpdate = new GmFlagUpdate();
gmFlagUpdate.setPoint("Point1");
gmFlagUpdate.setMyID("ID1");
gmFlagUpdate.setGMFlag("true");

try { 
gmFlagUpdated = myProxy.setGMFlag(gmFlagUpdate);         
log.info("IsgmFlagUpdated-->"+gmFlagUpdated); 
} catch (OperationFaultException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SystemFaultException e) {
e.printStackTrace(); 
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem is it gives me the following error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at $Proxy28.setGMFlag(Unknown Source)
at com.kunal.gm.MyServiceFacade.main(MyServiceFacade.java:84)
```

And the line : 84 is this line `gmFlagUpdated = myProxy.setGMFlag(gmFlagUpdate);` inside the try block.

The strange thing is, i have tried out another operation of the same WS and it's returning me a perfect response.

Is there something that i am doing wrong here ? or is it because the WSDL that i am using has perhaps been recently updated/changed ?

**EDIT :**

**getProxy() Implementation :**

```
public static MyService  getProxy() {
    URL url = null;
    try {
    URL baseUrl =  com.kunal.gm.service.MyService_Service.class.getResource("/com/kunal/gm/");
    url = new URL(baseUrl, "file:./MyWSDL.wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
    System.out.println(malformedURLException.toString());
    }

    QName serviceName = new QName("http://com.host.provider/deploy/service","MyService");
    MyService_Service service = new MyService_Service(url, serviceName);
    MyService myPort = service.getPort();
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) myPort;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,"https://endpoint.com.myWSDL");
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,"username");
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,"password");
return myPort;
}
```

Any suggestions/help is deeply appreciated .

Comment: It would be nice to have the implementation of the getProxy() method

Comment: Okay , i will edit the question to include that.

Comment: @gastush : Edited with code for `getProxy()` method.